# How can I get a directory listing from DOS in Perl?

Tags: perl, dos, external-process

I need to get directory names from the path passed to the Perl script as run time argument.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
$command ="cd $ARGV[0]";
system($command);

$command="dir /ad /b";
system($command);
@files=`$command`;
```

But it still returns the directory names inside the directory from which I'm running this Perl script.
In short, how do I get the directory names from a target directory whose path is passed to this Perl script?

Comment: while its entirely your choice, i still would advice against using system calls like that unnecessarily since Perl has its in built ways to do that. you make your code not portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also work
`$command = "dir /ad /b $ARGV[0]" ;`

Answer (score 9):

judging from what you are trying to do in your question post

```
$dir = $ARGV[0];
chdir($dir);
while(<*>){
 chomp;
 # check for directory;
 if ( -d $_ ) {
    print "$_\n" ;
 }
}
```

on the command line

```
c:\test> perl myscript.pl c:\test
```

There are other methods of doing a listing of directory. See these from documentation

1. [`perldoc -f opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html), [`perldoc -f readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)
2. [`perldoc perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)
3. [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)
4. [`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/perlfunc.html) (look at operators for testing files. `-x`, `-d`, `-f` etc)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that running "cd" via "system" does not change the working directory of the perl process. To do so, use the "chdir" function:

```
chdir($ARGV[0]);

$command="dir /ad /b";
system($command);
@files=`$command`;
```

Comment: To clarify, `system` in the question's code starts a child process, namely `cd`, which __does__ change __its own__ working directory. Then the child process ends; but environmental changes such as working directory and environment variables have no effect on the parent process, i.e. the Perl script.

Answer (score 0):

use [File::DosGlob](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::DosGlob) (core since before perl v5.5) to avoid gotchas like skipping files matching /^\./.

```
perl -MFile::DosGlob=glob -lwe "chdir 'test_dir'; print for grep {-d} <*>"
```